# Joda Time comparison crash - The end instant must be greater than the start

Tags: java, android, jodatime

I am currently implementing the pull-to-refresh feature into my `ListView`, however I have run into an issue.

I am doing a comparison using Joda Time between the current time, and a time I am retrieving from Parse of the last object update. The problem is, the comparison is not precise enough and unless the update happened more than a minute before, I get this crash -

```
The end instant must be greater than the start
```

I can't figure out how I can resolve this. Is there a way I can be more precise about the comparison (include seconds)?

Here's my code:

```
    Interval interval = new Interval(currentAttraction.updated, new Instant());
    Period period = interval.toPeriod();
```

**UPDATE:**

For some reason the 'updated' time that I receive from parse.com seems to be delayed by about 10-15 seconds. Anyone have any suggestions about how I could get around this? Possibly by subtracting ~15 seconds from the updated time?

Comment: The `Instant` represented by `currentAttraction.updated` is simply after the current time, i.e. `currentAttraction.updated.isAfter(new Instant())` is true.

Comment: It's definitely not after. The crash occurs when the minute is the same.

Comment: "It's definitely not after" Your error message "The end instant must be greater than the start" begs to differ.

Comment: `Interval(ReadableInstant, ReadableInstant)` calls the `BaseInterval(ReadableInstant, ReadableInstant)` constructor, which, for non-null arguments, compares the `ReadableInstant.getMillis()` value for the two arguments.

Comment: Ah, I apologise. You are correct. Here is the output of an object that I updated seconds before opening the app. For some reason the updated time seems to be delayed. `D/Updated: 2016-01-26T00:05:53.325Z
D/Current: 2016-01-26T00:05:48.174Z`

Comment: It seems to have been a parse issue. I've just tried it again this morning and all is working fine.